# How to remove auxiliary products from FB app?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I wanted to check what that button `+Add Product` do, added two products and now I want to delete them. But it seems FB doesn't provide any any UI to delete products from apps. Does anybody know how to get rid of them?

[image]

Comment: Why would you want to remove one of the tabs? The presence of the tab won't affect your app's operation, you'd still need to configure any relevant settings for the feature

Answer (score 40):

Lol, those products cannot be removed. FB doesn't have options for that. Here is an answer

[image]

https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1270595229673799

Comment: That is kind of weird ^^ ... well I guess I cannot really test, whether the facebook-login product is the reason my login calls to FB.LogInWithReadPermissions do not terminate (call the callback) anymore ...

Comment: That's strange, my server-to-server app review fails, and I have this Facebook Login product that I don't need and they need to verify that I have the right buttons on my site when I don't even use it for my app